# How do I handle react-native-meteor DDP connection failure?

Tags: meteor, react-native, react-native-meteor

In [this example](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-meteor#example-usage) you connect to Meteor with code like this

```
Meteor.connect('ws://192.168.X.X:3000/websocket');//do this only once
```

This is an asynchronous method and, as result, it returns nothing and it also doesn't accept a callback and `Meteor.status()` right after it will return `connected == false`. So the only solution I can see is to wrap this check into `setTimeout` callback with timeout set to, say 5s. Then, in case `Meteor.status().connected` is still `false` to show an error in UI. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Hi! have you solved this? It will be really nice to have an evento to dispatch if DDP connection is lost...

Comment: Hi. No. Hadn't solved.

Answer (score 3):

On react-native-meteor you have access to DDP protocol so you can check for DDP status like this:

```
Meteor.ddp.on('connected', () => {
  console.info('Conection con server stablished.');
});
```

And

```
Meteor.ddp.on('disconnected', () => {
  console.info('Disconnected from server.');
});
```

You can also listen for all DDP events exposed here https://github.com/mondora/ddp.js/#public-events